Apoyo para encontrar error sintaxis
Gracias por sus recomendaciones, A. Cedano, entiendo que para ti sea un tema fácil por la experiencia que has de tener, sin embargo, no todos tenemos la experiencia que posees cuando estamos iniciando en el mundo de la programación, pero agradezco tu comentario.
Por otro lado, les comento, el programa que intento desarrollar, tiene la siguiente estructura:
Login
Página principal
Nuevo Registro (y el archivo para procesar la información que se añada)
Código para agregar nuevos datos a base:
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('verificarDatos/config.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['email']) != "") {
        $fullName   = $_SESSION['fullName'];
        $titular   = $_SESSION['titular'];
        $email      = $_SESSION['email'];
        $idArea = $_SESSION['area'];
        $seccion = $_SESSION['seccion'];
        $fondo = $_SESSION['fondo'];
        $idUser     = $_SESSION['id'];
    ?>
    
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <title> Nuevo Registro</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <div class="container" style="padding-top:15px">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>NUEVO REGISTRO</h3>
            </div>
            
            
            <form method="POST" action="guardar_col.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="fondo">Fondo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"   value ="<?php echo $fondo; ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="seccion">Sección</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seccion" name="seccion" value ="<?php echo $seccion; ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="subseccion">Sub-Sección</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subseccion" name="subseccion" value ="<?php echo $idArea; ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones" name="observaciones">
                    </div>
                                        
                </div>
                <br />
                
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:15px">
                    <a href="colaborador.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

         

Como pueden observar, los datos “fondo, sección y subseccion” se obtienen de mi base datos, por lo que la información no es editable en dichos campos.
Si realizo el guardado de datos sin agregar algún otro campo, el registro se guarda correctamente.
Si agrego el siguiente campo:
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones" name="observaciones">
</div>

              

Al momento de guardar los datos muestra error de sintaxis.
Dejo los códigos y los mensajes de error:
Código para procesar el guardado de los datos
Codigo para procesar datos a guardar:
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion) SELECT fondo, seccion, nombre_area FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario ='$idUser'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;
¿>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row text-center">
                <?php if($resultado) { ?>
                    <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <a href="colaborador.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Codigo para guardar los datos del input “observaciones”
<?php
    
    require 'conexion.php';

    $observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion) SELECT fondo, seccion, nombre_area, $observaciones AS 'observaciones' FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario ='$idUser'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;
    
?>

Mensaje de error:
Error fatal : mysqli_sql_exception no detectada: Columna desconocida 'Prueba' en 'lista de campos' en C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\guardar_col.php:27 Rastreo de pila: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\guardar_col.php(27): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO pru...') #1 {main} arrojado en C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\guardar_col.php en la línea 27
Entiendo que puede ser algo demasiado sencillo, recién comienzo en la programación y por ende, desconozco aun como solucionarlo.
Gracias comunidad.

Estas intentando insertar 4 columnas de usuario en 3 de prueba

He añadido un campo a la tabla “prueba” y de igual manera a mi formulario y mis código para añadir el texto que ingrese el usuario, aun así no me permite guardar los datos

He realizado esta modificación:
query($sql);
 $id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;
 
?>
Hola Omar. El mensaje de error no me cuadra con el código que muestras en la pregunta. Dicho mensaje dice: Columna desconocida 'Prueba' en 'lista de campos' en C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\guardar_col.php:27 ¿Podrías por favor indicar cuál de todos es el archivo guardar_col.php y ¿cuál es la línea 27 de dicho archivo? En todo el código no veo ninguna instrucción SQL que use como nombre de columna una columna llamada Prueba, a no ser que alguna de tus variables tengan en su contenido backticks, lo cual haría que SQL reconozca esos valores como columnas...

Problema 1:
Estás insertando directamente variables de tipo literal en la consulta SQL sin comillas. Arréglalo colocando comillas simples.
Solución:
$sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion, observaciones) SELECT '$fondo', '$seccion', '$nombre_area', '$observaciones' FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario ='$idUser'";

No se, pero sospecho que puede ser posible que id_usuario sea de tipo numérico, ya que generalmente los IDs son números. En ese caso, no debes ponerlo entre comillas simples. Entonces, la corrección quedaría de esta manera:
$sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion, observaciones) SELECT '$fondo', '$seccion', '$nombre_area', '$observaciones' FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = $idUser";

Problema 2:
La consulta está fallando porque estás haciendo un INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion) y luego intentando agregar la columna observaciones en el SELECT, pero no la has incluido en la lista de columnas en la primera parte del INSERT. Debes incluir la columna observaciones explícitamente.
La solución sería asegurarse de que todas las columnas estén alineadas correctamente en el INSERT y el SELECT. El código corregido debería verse así:
$sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (fondo, seccion, subseccion, observaciones) SELECT fondo, seccion, nombre_area, '$observaciones' FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = $idUser";


Buenos días Stina Andersson, gracias por tu explicación, problema solucionado.
Muchas gracias
